# Getting a typedef that does not depend on templates of a templated class

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

Apologies in advance if this is a duplicate - I was not able to find my answer here. I have the following class:

```
template <typename T>
class A {
public:
    using X = double;

private:
    T x;
};
```

Now, I would like to obtain `A<T>::X`. Is that possible to do without declaring T?

I tried something along the lines:

```
template <typename T>
using B = A<T>::X;

B e = 0;
```

But that clearly does not work without specifying the template.

Comment: It does not work because `A` is not a class, it's a *template* for a class. You need the actual class, not the template.

Comment: How would that work if there were specializations of `A`?

Comment: It isn't possible because someone might do `template <> class A<SomeType> { public: using X = int; };` so there is no way to know if `A<SomeType>::X` is `double` unless you check.

Comment: If you think it doesn't matter because you know you will not do specializations just use `A<int>::X`.

Comment: Yes, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the quick reply! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firs, the keyword `typename` is needed for defining the `B` *alias template*:

```
template <typename T>
using B = typename A<T>::X;
```

The reason is that `X` is a *dependent name*: a name inside a template with a yet-to-be-determined parameter `T`.

---

Since `B` is an alias *template* taking a *type template parameter* (i.e.: `T`), that parameter has to be provided in order to determine `X`, for example if `T` is `int`:

```
B<int> e = 0;
```

However, note that this may not be valid or work as you expected for every `T`, since the `A` class template could have been *specialized* having the name `X` representing something completely different. For example, `X` could represent a type other than `double`:

```
template<>
class A<float> { 
public:
    using X = int; // not double!
};
```

The name `X` could represent a *data member* instead of a type:

```
template<>
class A<char> { 
public:
    static constexpr int X = 1; // not a type!
};
```

or it may not exist at all:

```
template<> class A { /* not name X */};
```